# Changing Active Directory Password via Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory

I'm trying to write a batch script to automatically change the password of an active directory user.

The:

`net user <user> /domain <password>`

where `<user>` & `<password>` are a user and password of some user on the domain.

Results in:

> The request will be processed at a domain controller for
>   domain .
>
> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

*Edit:

I just found out that you need to be the **domain controller** to be able to run the command.

Is the a way to change a user's password without being the domain controller?*

Comment: It would seem that you (or whichever account is executing the batch file) don't have the required permissions to reset to users password :-)

Comment: Yes, but what kind of permissions should I have?
Or is there a way to run a similar command using the user's credentials?

Comment: If you are trying to change another users password you need to be a domain admin.

Comment: But what if I have their credentials? Or I can log on as that user?

Comment: @AlexWeitz, look at using the [runas](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command if you have the users existing credentials.

Comment: The extended right you need on the target user account object is literally called **Reset Password** (no, you don't _need_ to be a Domain Admin (nor a Domain Controller) to do this). Talk to your Active Directory administrator about delegating this permission to the user account that's going to perform the change. If this is done _from_ the users machine and you have their credentials handy, do a **Change Password** operation instead. It's going to be much easier to automate in PowerShell than cmd though

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'm gonna try that tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT Admins with permissions to change passwords can use the QAD Powershell cmdlets to change passwords for accounts. Here’s an example of the Powershell command to run:

`Set-QADUser -Identity <account_name> -Proxy -UserPassword <new_password>`

For users without elevated permissions to set passwords on other accounts, there is still a Powershell option. You will need to have the Microsoft ActiveDirectory powershell module installed and know the previous password. Here’s some sample code how to accomplish this:

`Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity <ADAccount>`

This will then prompt for the previous password, and then ask for the new password twice.

For example if you want your process perform automatically:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $username -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $oldPass -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $newPass -Force)
```